# SQL Removing Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the below case statement

```
***, CASE WHEN Attributes LIKE ',Size = %,' Then  right(Attributes, len(Attributes) - charindex('Size  ', Attributes)) ELSE '' END as Size***
```

To get the below result

***,Size = XXL ,Fits to Chest Size = 48 to 50 in,,Closure Type = Snap Button ,Material = Cotton ,Color = Khaki ,Sleeve Length = 33 in,Lining Material = Polyester Thread ,,Fabric Weight = 9 oz,,,Resists = Flame ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,***

I want to remove everything and only have Size = XXL

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own functions...)

Comment: I AM Using MSSQL

Comment: You should also tag your SQL Server version.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not an ETL process, then you should really consider changing your data model so you that you do not have to parse your `Attribute` column every time.

Below is a short solution with

- [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) (SQL Server 2016 and later)
- [TRIM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) (SQL Server 2017 and later)

**Sample data**

```
create table CsvData
(
  Attribute nvarchar(1000)
);

insert into CsvData (Attribute) values
('Foo = 10,Bar = 20,,,,,Size = XXL ,Fits to Chest Size = 48 to 50 in,,Closure Type = Snap Button ,Material = Cotton ,Color = Khaki ,Sleeve Length = 33 in,Lining Material = Polyester Thread ,,Fabric Weight = 9 oz,,,Resists = Flame ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,');
```

**Solution**

```
select trim(s.value) as SizeAttribute
from CsvData cd
cross apply string_split(cd.Attribute, ',') s
where left(s.value, 4) = 'Size';
```

**Result**

```
SizeAttribute
-------------
Size = XXL
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e1dee3b2897d7a0c0f3f3a4ab4ad346) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @CsvData TABLE(Attribute nvarchar(1000));

insert into @CsvData (Attribute) values
('Foo = 10,Bar = 20,,,,,Size = XXL ,Fits to Chest Size = 48 to 50 in,,Closure Type = 
Snap Button ,Material = Cotton ,Color = Khaki ,Sleeve Length = 33 in,Lining Material = 
Polyester Thread ,,Fabric Weight = 9 oz,,,Resists = Flame ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,');


DECLARE @xml_value AS XML,
    @string_value AS VARCHAR(2000),
    @delimiter_value AS VARCHAR(15)
SET @string_value=(SELECT Attribute FROM @CsvData)
SET @delimiter_value =','
SET @xml_value = Cast(( '<studentname>'+ Replace(@string_value, @delimiter_value, '</studentname><studentname>') + '</studentname>' ) AS XML)
SELECT   x.m.query('.').value('.', 'VARCHAR(15)') AS VALUE
FROM   @xml_value.nodes('/studentname') AS x(m)
WHERE  x.m.query('.').value('.', 'VARCHAR(15)')  LIKE 'Size%'
```